# Selecting rows from ndarray via bytearray

Tags: numpy, redis-py

I have a bytearray that is pulled from redis.

```
r.set('a', '')
r.setbit('a', 0, 1)
r.setbit('a', 1, 1)
r.setbit('a', 12, 1)

a_raw = db.get('a')
# b'\xc0\x08'
a_bin = bin(int.from_bytes(a, byteorder="big")) 
# 0b1100000000001000
```

I want to use that bytearray to select rows from an ndarray.

```
arr = np.arange(12)
arr[a_raw]
# array([0, 1, 12])
```

---

**Edit** Both solutions work, but I found @paul-panzer's to be faster

```
import timeit

setup = '''import numpy as np; a = b'\\xc0\\x08'; '''

t1 = timeit.timeit('idx = np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(a, np.uint8)); np.where(idx)', 
              setup = setup, number=10000)

t2 = timeit.timeit('idx = np.array(list(bin(int.from_bytes(a, byteorder="big"))[2:])) == "1"; np.where(idx)',
              setup = setup, number=10000)

print(t1, t2)
#0.019560601096600294 0.054518797900527716
```

---

**Edit 2** Actually, the `from_bytes` method doesn't return what I'm looking for:

```
redis_db.delete('timeit_test')
redis_db.setbit('timeit_test', 12666, 1)
redis_db.setbit('timeit_test', 14379, 1)
by = redis_db.get('timeit_test')

idx = np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(by, np.uint8))
indices = np.where(idx)

idx = np.array(list(bin(int.from_bytes(by, byteorder="big"))[2:])) == "1"
indices_2 = np.where(idx)

print(indices, indices_2)
#(array([12666, 14379]),) (array([   1, 1714]),)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way using `unpackbits`:

```
>>> a = b'\xc0\x08'
>>> b = np.arange(32).reshape(16, 2)
>>> c = np.arange(40).reshape(20, 2)
>>> 
>>> idx = np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(a, np.uint8))
>>> 
# if the sizes match boolen indexing can be used
>>> b[idx.view(bool)]
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [24, 25]])
>>> 
# non matching sizes can be worked around using where
>>> c[np.where(idx)]
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [24, 25]])
>>>
```

Comment: Somewhat surprisingly to me, when using `%timeit` on a range of examples, I do not see any performance benefit for using `np.unpackbits` as opposed to directly creating a mask from the binary string.

Comment: @ely I suspect it's creating the binary string from the raw input that's expensive.

Comment: I thought that might be the case too, but it doesn't look like it. I added examples to my answer, at least for my machine using the same bytes data from the question. It makes me suspect that `unpackbits` is actually a good bit slower than just iterating and checking the binary digits, but that your approach ends up just slightly as the faster option because `frombuffer` won't copy data. But the point I guess is that the data copy, and even expanding it with `bin` and `list`, *barely* makes the other methods slower, especially using `struct`. It makes me curious about `unpackbits`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
In [57]: b = 0b1100000000001000

In [58]: mask = np.array(list(bin(b)[2:])) == '1'

In [59]: arr = np.arange(13)

In [60]: arr[mask[:len(arr)]]
Out[60]: array([ 0,  1, 12])
```

Additionally it's a simple check to demonstrate that the `__getitem__` implementation for `ndarray` does not support indexing directly on a `bytes` object:

```
In [61]: by = b'\xc0\x08'

In [62]: arr[by]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-111-6cd68003b176> in <module>()
----> 1 arr[by]

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) 
and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

So unless you subclass `ndarray` or create an extension module with customized `__getitem__` behavior, there is no way to do it directly from the `bytes`, and you must convert the bytes into a boolean mask based on bitwise conditions.

Here's an example comparing the timing for a few different approaches that work directly from the original `bytes` object:

```
In [171]: %timeit np.array(list(bin(int.from_bytes(by, byteorder='big'))[2:])) == '1'
3.51 µs ± 38 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [172]: %timeit np.unpackbits(np.frombuffer(by, np.uint8))
2.05 µs ± 29.59 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

In [173]: %timeit np.array(list(bin(struct.unpack('>H', by)[0])[2:])) == '1'
2.65 µs ± 6.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: This works thanks. I accepted the other one though because the performance is a little better.

Comment: @JacobEggers I actually do not see a better performance in that one, probably due to the need for `frombuffer` with a type cast in order to treat the `bytes` object as unsigned. Additionally, the variance of runtimes seems to be much higher for the `unpackbits` approach.

Comment: I don't know why I'm getting such different timing than you are. Using %timeit in my Jupyter notebook, I got: `4.91 µs ± 266 ns`, `1.42 µs ± 19.8 ns`, and `4.47 µs ± 182 ns` for the same code. What version of python/numpy are you using? I have 3.6.2 & 1.13.1

Comment: Also, they return different results for arrays. I'll add the code to my question.